# Use gnuplot to plot from c during runtime

Tags: c, gnuplot

I need some help regarding plotting from c using gnuplot:

My c source code calculates some points and stores their x/y values in arrays. It also calculates a polynomial fit by least squares for these points. Now I need to plot these points as well as the fitted function to a graph during the runtime of the c source code. I have no experience regarding gnuplot and the online resources of gnuplot are really hard to understand.

- Is the main idea to include a library that has commands to gnuplot and just feed my arrays to these functions?
- Can anyone give me an example of realizing this?

I´d be really thankful if anyone can help me with this very basic problem.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Figure out which one you're actually using.

Comment: Typically, you would use gnuplot to plot a text file of data you already have. gnuplot is a standalone program that runs scripts in its own scripting language, and generates output based on the script. It does not have an API like a library. You could hack something together with pipes, for example, but this is not a typical or expected way to use gnuplot.  I suggest writing output from your C program to a file, then process the file with gnuplot.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. I found [this page](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/) describing other libraries that provide "an interface" to gnuplot. But I think they all work by just generating a script on the fly and feeding the script and data through pipes to gnuplot running as a separate process. There is still no direct application interface (API) for gnuplot.

Answer (score 2):

If you really do need to use gnuplot from C, then you can use `popen()` to start a gnuplot process, and use `fprintf()` to send commands to it, like so:

```
void plot_array(float *x, float *y, int n) {
  FILE *p = popen("gnuplot", "w");

  fprintf(p, "plot - with lines\n");

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    fprintf(p, "%f %f\n", x[i], y[i]);

  fprintf(p, "e\n");
  ...
  pclose(p);
}
```

But, there are lots of plotting libraries around that provide you with a more idiomatic way of plotting arrays from C. If you can use C++, then there is the [gnuplot-iostream library](http://stahlke.org/dan/gnuplot-iostream/) that basically does the above for you.

Comment: You told: if you really need gnuplot in C ... . Is there some other way better than using GNU plot to plot in C?

Comment: @mohammadsdtmnd You could have your program just write out the datapoints and have it quit, and then call gnuplot to read in the datapoints and plot them. That could then be automated using a shell script. But if you really need to plot while the C program is still running, then you could also consider using a C library like [LibGD](https://libgd.github.io/) or [PLplot](https://plplot.sourceforge.net/).